# puppet dashboard installation with passenger shows default apache page

Tags: apache-http-server, puppet, passenger

I am trying to install puppet on my CentOS 6.5 64 bit machine.
The installation of puppet-server goes through fine and I am being able to install apache2.2.15 and passenger 4.0.53. I have installed puppet-dashboard too and configured with apache.

Everything is installed from scratch. 
Followed the tutorials available at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k51SY_o9hMo
and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHRHKKkCdTU for the installation of puppet server and puppet dashboard.

Now, when I try to access puppet dashboard I find 
..test:3000 is not accessible.

I therefore run the following to make sure 3000 port is accessible on the CentOS machine:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

Following that everytime the apache welcome page is displayed. If in /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf file I make changes as

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options Indexes ##### this originally was Options -Indexes 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

This starts listing the files at document root (below location) [This directory has a recursive 755 permission]:

```
/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/
```

But the actual dashboard is not getting displayed.

**I have not used default "puppet" as my hostname and while configuring mysql instead of 'user'@'localhost' I have used 'user'@'%'.**

/etc/httpd/conf.d/puppet-dash.conf file:

```
#LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.53
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

# you may want to tune these settings
PassengerHighPerformance on
PassengerMaxPoolSize 12
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1500
# PassengerMaxRequests 1000
PassengerStatThrottleRate 120
#RailsAutoDetect On

Listen 3000
<VirtualHost *:3000>
        ServerName masterpuppet.mydomain.test
        ServerAlias masterpuppet
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/
        <Directory /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/>
            Options None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/puppet-dashboard_error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/puppet-dashboard_access.log combined
  ......
</VirtualHost>
```

The /etc/puppet.puppet.conf file is:

```
[main]
# The Puppet log directory.
# The default value is '$vardir/log'.
logdir = /var/log/puppet

# Where Puppet PID files are kept.
# The default value is '$vardir/run'.
rundir = /var/run/puppet

# Where SSL certificates are kept.
# The default value is '$confdir/ssl'.
ssldir = $vardir/ssl

#Set up DNS
dns_alt_names = masterpuppet masterpuppet.mydomain.test

# Tell puppet where the environment directories live
environmentpath = $confdir/environments

# Confivure puppet to talk to puppet dashboard
reports = store, http
reporturl = http://masterpuppet.mydomain.test:3000/reports/upload
node_terminus = exec
external_nodes = /user/bin/env PUPPET_DASHBOARD_URL=http://masterpuppet.mydomain.test:3000 /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/bin/external_node
```

[agent]

```
# The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

# Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
# extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
# The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig

# Turn on reporting
report = true
```

The puppet.conf file is the default one taken from puppet lab documentation with necessary changes to point to passenger, and other locations. Certificate names are double checked and found to be correct.

A netstat -aln | grep 3000 shows the port 3000 is listening.

Now I am totally confused what is going wrong here. All documentation in puppet lab docs, othjer tutorial blogs look exactly the same what I did here. 
Is it like I need to use the default 'puppet' as hostname  or is there some trick that I am missing here.
Please let me know if any further information/clarification is needed to help me out!

Comment: Are you using Puppet Enterprise? If not, take a look at [foreman](http://theforeman.org). It makes installation very simple, and provides a nice frontend and External Node Classifier to open source Puppet.

Comment: Thanks Sheam89! I actually moved into PE 3.7 sometime after I posted the query. But anyway, thanks a lot for looking into the issue. It might be handy if I want to use open puppet sometime later.